# How to get Route template in Azure Functions isolated

Tags: azure-functions

I'd like to retrieve the route template of a particular HTTP triggered Azure Function on runtime, i.e. the value of Route parameter of HttpTrigger:

```cs
[Function(FunctionNames.GetInfoDefinition)]

public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetPerson([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, nameof(HttpMethod.Get), 
Route = $"{Version}/{PersonsRoute}/{{{PersonId}}}")]
    HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext, string personId)

{
    ...
}
```

How can I retrieve it? Ideally without the need to use reflection.